# SQL statement can't sum up to 100%

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't sum the total up to 100% while generating the SQL statement below.

SQL:

```
SELECT T.EventTypeName, 
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))),0) AS Nursing ,
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))),0) AS PatientEldery,
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END))),0) AS Disability 
FROM StEvent S, EventType T WHERE S.EventTypeId = T.EventTypeId GROUP BY T.EventTypeName
```

I expect the total to be 100%    [image]

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and what errors you are getting. Also please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Ans please do not use images as code samples: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: If all three columns are - say - 1/3 of the values, they will all be 33.3333...% which you seem to want to round to 33%. What would you like to be displayed then, since one column would need to be erroneously displayed as 34% to make it sum up to 100%.

Comment: Try and round to (for example) 2 decimal places. What values do you get now and what do the sum up to?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ASP.NET or MVC. It's a SQL question. I've edited your tags and description to reflect that. if you tag your questions accurately you're more likely to get people with the relevant expertise looking at them.

Comment: The typical solution to this issue, aside from increasing the precision of the percentages, is to add a note to the end along the lines of "the totals may not sum to 100% due to rounding". You can either have exact values or an exact total, but not, generally, both, except as mentioned by fudging the values (for example, making the last one equal `100 - SUM(all the rest)`. But this has its own, very obvious problems with distorting the actual numbers. This is not even SQL specific; you have the same issues in Excel, or indeed any report dealing with percentages.

Answer (score 0):

Use Sum instead and replace null by 0

```
SELECT T.EventTypeName, 
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS Nursing ,
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS PatientEldery,
ROUND(((COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((COUNT(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + COUNT(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + COUNT(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS Disability 
FROM StEvent S, EventType T WHERE S.EventTypeId = T.EventTypeId GROUP BY T.EventTypeName
```

**Edit**

Instead of COUNT use SUM

```
SELECT T.EventTypeName, 
    ROUND(((SUM(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((SUM(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + SUM(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS Nursing ,
    ROUND(((SUM(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((SUM(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + SUM(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS PatientEldery,
    ROUND(((SUM(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) * 100 / ((SUM(CASE Nursing WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) + SUM(CASE PatientEldery WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE Disability WHEN 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END))),0) AS Disability 
    FROM StEvent S, EventType T WHERE S.EventTypeId = T.EventTypeId GROUP BY T.EventTypeName
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help but all the results become 33 33 33 for each column . ^_^ so it can't read out the correct data QAQ.